# Is there any way to sort this kind of array?

Tags: arrays, numpy, sorting

I am trying to sort this kind of array:

```
array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.46938776, 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.53061224, 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]])
```

My code is this:

```
def selection_sort(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
         swap = i + np.argmin(x[i:])
         (x[i], x[swap]) = (x[swap], x[i])
    return x



selection_sort(output)
```

I have also tried using this too:

```
 print(np.sort(arr))
```

but unfortunately not working Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go with a direct example,

```
# What you did
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3]])
print('Shape', x.shape, 'Length', len(x))
# What should be done to make your code work
y = np.array([1, 2, 3])
print('Shape', y.shape, len(y))
```

If you consider the aforementioned example, the variable `x` contains a list inside a list, therefore a 2D list (for clarity, I'm not considering numpy matrix). Therefore, the length you are getting is the size of the last dimension (in this case, 1). On the contrary, the variable `y` contains the same value, but it only contains a single list (not a list inside a list, as there is only one square bracket). So, the length of `y` is 3.

The value of `x` you defined in the question is the same way I defined in my aforementioned script as `x`. As the length of the variable `x` is 1, the `selection_sort` you are trying to perform gets stuck on index `1`. You can solve the issue by following the variable declaration as I did for the variable `y`.

Furthermore, I believe `print(np.sort(arr))` should work. It works in my case. I believe you did something wrong or missed something, as a result, you are thinking `np.sort()` is not working. As the information/error is not clear, I am waiting for your review.